# Is it safe to call the same method several times asynchronously in C# 5

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I would be grateful if you could let me know opinion about calling asynchronously the same method several times. I more interested in know the safety side of this activities.  I have posted here a console code that contain one method that I am calling asynchronously four times and it is working well. So far I have not noted any hiccups. But I want to be sure. Please the following code:

```
public class OneMethodCalledServeralTimes
    {
        protected async Task<bool> DoSomeWork(Values values, int whenItIsCalled, string description)
        {
            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();

            await Task.Delay(values.Value);

            Console.WriteLine("{0} Completed in {1} and this was called: {2}",description, stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds, whenItIsCalled);

            return true;
        }

        public bool DoAllWork()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("=====================Started doing weekend Chores===================");
            var task1 = DoSomeWork(new Values { Value = 10000 }, 1, "First work to be done");
            var task2 = DoSomeWork(new Values {Value = 7000}, 1, "First work to be done");
            var task3 = DoSomeWork(new Values { Value = 4000 }, 2, "second work to be done");
            var task4 = DoSomeWork(new Values { Value = 1000 }, 3, "third work to be done");

            Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3, task4);

            Console.WriteLine("=====================Completed doing weekend Chores===================");

            return true;
        }

    }
```

The following is the Console application calling the above call:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //var weekend = new HomeWork().DoAllWork();

            Console.WriteLine("############################Using proper methods#############################");


            var workToBeDone= new OneMethodCalledServeralTimes().DoAllWork(); //Passing parameters and the most successful one

            Console.WriteLine("It took the entire four mothod {0} seconds to finish", stopewach.ElapsedMilliseconds/1000.0);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

I also highly welcome any concise views about the corns and pros of calling asynchronously the same method several times

Comment: There's nothing *inherently* dangerous to calling the same method asynchronously multiple times. There's nothing inherently *safe* about it either. It would depend entirely on what the method *does*. Does it have side effects? Does it share any state or any resources? If so, are those resources thread-safe?

Comment: @neminem That was so succinct I would put that into an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @neminem: I was writing up something very similar as an answer :)

Comment: Well dang. Now I'm sad I didn't put it as an answer. I didn't think it was specific enough. Still, if I didn't get rep, at least I got a comment from Jon Skeet saying his answer was like mine; that's worth something. :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on the method - but it's certainly not inherently *unsafe*. There's nothing within the state machine generated by the compiler that introduces problems. However, if your asynchronous method uses shared state, then the normal caveats apply. For example, you wouldn't want to call this multiple threads concurrently:

```
static Task DoBadThingsAsync(List<string> list)
{
    await Task.Delay(500);
    list.Add("Hello!");
}
```

... because `List<T>` isn't safe to use in a multi-threaded environment if any of the threads perform writes (without synchronization).

One point to note is that if you've got asynchronous methods which are expected to be used in a "single thread synchronization context" (e.g. the UI thread in a WPF or WinForms app) then you don't need to worry about *thread* safety - but you do need to worry about general concurrency, as both invocations of the method could be "live" at the same time.

Comment: Many thanks for the prompt replies. Your points are all valid. However, one more thing I would like to share with you is: I modify the method as shown below, you will not that even though this is asynchronous method, it would behave like synchronous method! It will do one job at a time. If I create four methods and call them asynchronously, they will all be in parallel manor.

Comment: protected async Task<bool> DoSomeWork(Values values, int whenItIsCalled, string description)
        {
            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();

            long count = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < values.Value; i++)
            {
                count++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("{0} Completed in {1} and this was called: {2} and the count is {3}", description, stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds, whenItIsCalled, count);

            return true;
        }

Comment: @Max: It's not really a great idea to add code in comments like this - it's basically unreadable. But basically you've got no `await` expressions, so yes, it *will* run synchronously.

Comment: Jon and the members of the forum, please accept my sincere apologies for posting the code in the comment area. I shall not do this again. In the meantime, many thanks for pointing out the missing "await".